# Plotting with full dates as the axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I am having trouble with x-axis of my data. Currently, it looks like this.

`[201909240908, 201909240956, 201909241002, ...`] It is in `YYYYMMDDHHMM` format. Not only is this graph wrong (it should not be a straight line in the middle), it is also hard to read.

[image]

How can I change my a-axis data while still retaining the date? Ideally, the x-axis value would show up as `DDHHMM` on the bottom with the year and month hidden.

---

**Update**

The dates show up a lot better now. But the intervals are equal instead of being accurate.

[image]

Comment: I tried changing the x-axis data by doing this for every value in that list `x_val = x_val - first_x_val`

Comment: Are you specifying `YYYYMMDDHHMM` somewhere in code to parse it? It will cause confusion since `MM` is being used to represent both month and minute

Comment: @Saharsh Yeah, that format was just to help the reader see what it means. This is how it actually works. `int(f'{entry.year}{pad_number(entry.month, 2)}{pad_number(entry.day, 2)}{entry.time}')`

Comment: makes sense. Mind if you can post the code here? I might be able to understand how are you doing this.

Comment: @Saharsh The code for getting of the x-axis info? https://pastebin.com/uqMJLczG The entire code need to run this is quite long so I only included the part that gets the x-axis values

Comment: Apologies but pastebin is blocked in my organization `*-*!`

Comment: http://dpaste.com/0MMBY26

Comment: Have you tried to put your data into a `pandas.DataFrame`?  `plotly` works very nicely with DataFrames.  Then, you can use the `datetime` functionality (which is built-into pandas) and format your dates using the `%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S` string formatting.  Also, change the x-axis type to `category` to remove the straight line.  Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52599209/6340496)

Comment: @S3DEV The examples I am seeing for datetime only have a date, not a time, how do I pass date + time into pandas?

Comment: @Vader - If we use your dates list above and call it `dates`; try this:  `df_dates['MyDates'] = pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%Y%m%d%H%M').strftime('%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')`  This is telling pandas how to interpret your dates, and the output format you'd like.

Comment: @S3DEV thank you, that brings me a significant step closer. The intervals don't make sense though they are all spaced out even when the times themselves are not like that.

Comment: @Vader - Excellent. Working on an example (as an answer) for you now ...

Comment: @S3DEV here is the list as I had it initially if you want it. http://dpaste.com/27Z685T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be two issues here:

1. Date formatting
2. Linear spacing in the graph - (not addressed)

**Date Formatting:**
This answer addresses the date formatting issue, using your date list.  We'll use a `pandas.DataFrame` to handle the formatting and passing of data into `plotly`, as they work very nicely together.

Here is the sample code with comments.  **I've simulated the values, but the dates are yours.**

**Linear Spacing:**
Unfortunately I was not able to find a way to have a date axis, with representative (non-equal) spacing between dates.  Any one else?  But the code solution below enables you to use dates as your xaxis using the `'type': 'category'` argument on the xaxis.

I've not applied any pretty formatting to the output graph - that's up to you.  :-)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import plot

# Builing date range from yours.
dates = [201909240908, 201909240956, 201909241002, 201909241056, 201909241113, 201909241156, 
         201909241200, 201909241227, 201909241256, 201909241301, 201909241356, 201909241456, 
         201909241547, 201909241556, 201909241648, 201909241656, 201909241704, 201909241756, 
         201909241936, 201909241956, 201909242008, 201909242056, 201909242151, 201909242156, 
         201909242218, 201909242256, 201909242315, 201909242356, 201909250041, 201909250056, 
         201909250057, 201909250156, 201909250200, 201909250256, 201909250356, 201909250400, 
         201909250456, 201909250556, 201909250656, 201909250756, 201909250856, 201909250956, 
         201909251056, 201909251156, 201909251256, 201909251356]
# Simulate values.
values = np.random.randint(250, 350, len(dates)).tolist()

# Add dates and values to a DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': dates, 'Values': values})
# Format your dates.
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%Y%m%d%H%M').strftime('%Y-%d-%m %H:%M')

# Create plot.
trace = go.Scatter(x=df['Dates'], y=df['Values'])
layout = {}
layout.update({'xaxis': {'type': 'category'}})
layout.update({'yaxis': {'range': [0, 400]}})
fig = {'data': [trace], 'layout': layout}
plot(fig)
```

**Date Formatting Alternative:**
An alternative for converting your dates into a list of `datetime` objects (and leaving out the DataFrame) is:

```
datesf = [pd.datetime.strptime(str(date), "%Y%m%d%H%M") for date in dates]
```

This will return:

```
[datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 24, 9, 8), datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 24, 9, 56), ... ]
```

Comment: this is what worked for me `dates_new = [pd.datetime.strptime(str(dt_int), "%Y%m%d%H%M") for dt_int in dates]` If you want to update the answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Vader - There you are.  Thank you!