# Removing gaps between data on a Plotly graph

Tags: python, graph, plotly, finance

I was trying to make a graph plotting time series data on stock prices. However markets are only open 9:30-16:00 but the graph automatically plots times where the market isn't open. This leads to there being large lines on the graph between data points, this should be more apparent in the picture that I've attached. If anybody could help resolve this issue I'd appreciate it.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objects as go

#Initial data & get dataframe 
start = dt.date(2022,3,1)
end = dt.date(2022,3,7)
ticker = 'SPY'
df = yf.download(ticker,start,end,progress=False,interval='1m')

#Make Graph
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['Adj Close'],
    mode='lines'))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python plotly date axis as string not dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551957/python-plotly-date-axis-as-string-not-dates)   `fig.update_layout(xaxis={'type':'category'})`

Comment: @Chris that works but will lead to plotly interpreting the datetimes as different categories so the tickmarks will be evenly spaced apart even if the difference in time between the tickmarks aren't the same

Comment: @DerekO I believe that's what he wants

Comment: @Chris yeah that's a fair point. i would say as a more generalizable solution, it might be preferrable to try using the parameter `connectgaps` but I haven't had a chance to see whether or not that produces a similar result to your suggestion

Comment: You should only handle this problem with pandas before you plot it. You can remove all entries dated before 09:30 am and after 16:00.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a rangebreak to create a discontinuous x-axis scale.  Here I use the bounds method to do this.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
# !pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

#Initial data & get dataframe 
start = dt.date(2023,4,15)
end = dt.date(2023,4,21)
ticker = 'SPY'
df = yf.download(ticker,start,end,progress=False,interval='1m')


def calc_rangebreak(time_series:pd.Series):
    """ Caculate the bounds of missing data
    
    returns: list of dictionaries suitable for plotly rangebreak
    """

    timedeltas = time_series.diff()

    if len(time_series) < 2:
        return []

    # find index of the gaps where it is 50% greater than the median time interval
    missing_times = np.where([timedeltas > timedeltas.median()*1.5])[1]

    #Tiny offset to account for numerical precision
    off = pd.Timedelta(seconds=0.0001)

    rb = [{'bounds': [str((time_series.iloc[t-1]+off)), str((time_series.iloc[t]-off))]} for t in missing_times]
    return rb

#Make Graph
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['Adj Close'],
    mode='lines'))


rangebreak_bounds = calc_rangebreak(df.index.to_series())

fig.update_xaxes(rangebreaks=rangebreak_bounds)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This approach does nothing to remove the gaps from the plot, as requested by the OP.

Comment: @lazarea. Thanks, you are right, I originally misread the question. I changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You very much for your help!
Your decision helped me to remove gaps not only in price, but in indicators on subplots below.
Easy decision: fig.update_layout(xaxis={'type':'category'}) - remove gaps only in price. So, if you use some indicators below, it stay with gaps.

Comment: Hi, please keep the answer section for answers only. You can thank someone in the comments when you are able to

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34678101)